# Remove MIDI default output from sequencer

Tags: java, midi

I can't seem to be able to turn off the default output of the sequencer in Java. I always get the standard MIDI sound while sending messages to another port.

**Finding my Port**

```
Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();

MidiDevice.Info[] midiDeviceInfos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();

// 1 is the port I want
MidiDevice midiOutDevice = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(midiDeviceInfos[1]);

Receiver midiOutReceiver = midiOutDevice.getReceiver();
sequencer.getTransmitter().setReceiver(midiOutReceiver);
```

This causes a MIDI Unavailable Exception: MIDI IN receiver not available.

Unless I change it to (which gets me the desired port), but still the default MIDI:

```
Receiver midiOutReceiver = MidiSystem.getReceiver();
sequencer.getTransmitter().setReceiver(midiOutReceiver);
```

**Can't remove any Transmitters or Receivers**

```
sequencer.getTransmitters().remove(INT)
sequencer.getReceivers().remove(INT)
```

Now no matter what I do, I always hear the default MIDI output from the sequencer (This gave me a compiling error)

How can I send MIDI to only 1 port, without the standard port of the sequencer in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found a way to avoid the default connections the sequencer object has. You have the option to choose the default sequencer by not passing any parameter. But if you pass a boolean with the getSequencer method you can choose!

```
Sequencer seq = MidiSystem.getSequencer(false);
```